# Managed property boost

Tags: search, fast

If i have two managed properties say "A" and "B". And in the results my search phrase in some results is found in "A" and in some results is found in "B". Then i want to ensure that the results which contains search phrase in "A" should come first(should be boosted) than "B"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my answer from my blog:

You can try to add a managed property boost on A where you match on #. Or you can use FQL and xrank. Something like below where you query for "my query", but boost the items where the same query appears in A.

xrank(string("my query", mode="simpleall"), A:string("my query", mode="simpleall"), boost=5000)

Comment: hi @Mikael i would appreciate if you look this [How to search in selected properties](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82865/search-in-selected-managed-properties)