# Search in selected managed properties

Tags: 2010, search, search-results, fast-search

I need to search my query only in specific managed properties.
Currently I am having results which do not contain the query to be search.

How can I restrict so that search is done only in `a b c` managed properties?
I am using FAST search and have created a scope.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to restrict to only these properties

```
a:"myPropertySearchA" OR b:"myPropertySearchB" OR C:"myPropertySearchD"
```

Reference: [Using Operators in Keyword Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee872310%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and [Property Restriction Keyword Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff394509%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Benny. But i want it to be configured somewhere at the backend. i dont want this to get displayed in URL. may be in configurations that only these properties should be searchable

Comment: Then you're looking for something like what's described in the article [Walkthrough: Creating a Basic Search Web Part Using the Query Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms551453.ASPX) I guess?

Comment: Not exactly. No Custom webpart i want. I want that Fast search should not include my query in selected search results. query should be search only in selected properties but other properties which are associated with searchable properties will be displayed.

Comment: I suggest adding the properties as an a= parameter, and have them show in the URL. Your other option would be a custom web part inheriting the core results web part, which injects your filter.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is PropertyName:"Query". In your case it would be:

```
a:"Query" OR b:"Query" OR c:"Query"
```

or

```
a:"Query" AND b:"Query" AND c:"Query"
```